# Oracle: problems to insert simbol '&'

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, special-characters

Im trying to insert the next query in Oracle SQL Developer

```
insert into table1 (specialString) values ("&&test");
```

but The SQL ask me for a var value

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or... SET SCAN OFF, which tell's sql developer's statement/script engines to not do replacements for &'s

```
clear screen
drop table so;
set scan off
CREATE TABLE SO (WORDS VARCHAR2(256));
INSERT INTO SO VALUES ('&&test');
select * from so;
```

[image]